# How to include C code inside OSGI bundle

Tags: java, c, maven, java-native-interface, osgi

I'm working on OSGI bundle which uses Java native interface. I use this makefile to build the .so module:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
#
# Makefile for native stuff
#

# c files to compile
C_SOURCES   := sqrt.c

# the name of the library to build
LIBNAME     := sqrt

C_SOURCE_DIR    := src
C_GENSOURCE_DIR := src

TARGET_DIR  := ../../../target
C_BUILD_DIR    = $(TARGET_DIR)/native
JAVA_BUILD_DIR = $(TARGET_DIR)/classes

# the name of the file we build
TARGET      = $(JAVA_BUILD_DIR)/META-INF/lib/$(LIB_PREFIX)$(LIBNAME)$(LIB_EXTN)

# find the jdk. if this doesn't work for you, define JAVA_HOME in your
# environment or on the make command line
JAVA_HOME ?= /opt/jdk1.7.0_02

# classpath for javah
JAVAH_CLASSPATH = `cat $(TARGET_DIR)/compile-classpath`

# tools and options
CFLAGS = -Wall -fpic
CPPFLAGS = -I$(C_SOURCE_DIR) -I$(C_GENSOURCE_DIR) -Iinclude \
    -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include
JAVAH = /opt/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/javah
JAVAH_FLAGS += -classpath $(JAVAH_CLASSPATH)
JAVAH_CMD = $(JAVAH) $(JAVAH_FLAGS) $(OUTPUT_OPTION)
LDFLAGS = -shared
LINK.so = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LD_LIBS)

ifdef DEBUG
CFLAGS += -g
LDFLAGS += -g
endif

# os-dependent bits
UNAME := $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
LIB_PREFIX = lib
LIB_EXTN = .so
CPPFLAGS += -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
else
ifeq ($(findstring CYGWIN,$(UNAME)),CYGWIN)
LIB_PREFIX =
LIB_EXTN = .dll
CPPFLAGS += -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/win32
else
f := $(error Platform $(UNAME) not supported)
endif
endif

# we look in $(C_SOURCE_DIR) for c files...
vpath %.c $(C_SOURCE_DIR)

# convenience variables
C_OBJFILES = $(addprefix $(C_BUILD_DIR)/,$(subst .c,.o,$(C_SOURCES)))

# default target
all: $(TARGET)

# rule to compile the .c files
$(C_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p `dirname $@`
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

# link the C objects into a shared library
$(TARGET): $(C_OBJFILES) $(LDLIBS)
    @mkdir -p `dirname $@`
    $(LINK.so) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^

# a rule to build the .h file with javah                    
$(C_GENSOURCE_DIR)/org_DX_57_osgi_NB_27_impl_Sqrt.h: $(JAVA_BUILD_DIR)/org/DX_57/osgi/NB_27/impl/Sqrt.class
    rm -f $@                
    $(JAVAH) $(JAVAH_FLAGS) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) org.DX_57.osgi.NB_27.impl.Sqrt

# the .o file depends on the .h file
$(C_BUILD_DIR)/sqrt.o: $(C_GENSOURCE_DIR)/org_DX_57_osgi_NB_27_impl_Sqrt.h

clean::
    rm -f $(C_OBJFILES)
    rm -f $(TARGET)
    rm -f $(C_BUILD_DIR)/jnirules.mak
```

This Makefile successfully generates header files and compiles .o file. The problem is that when the bundle is compiled the .so file is not packaged insight the bundle.
This is the content of the POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.DX_57.osgi.NB_27</groupId>
        <artifactId>NB_27</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>NB_27-impl</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>NB_27-impl</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>NB_27-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
           <id>build-native</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <property name="native.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                <echo file="${project.build.directory}/compile-classpath" message="${native.classpath}" />
                <exec dir="src/main/native" executable="make" failonerror="true" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>${pom.groupId}.api, org.osgi.framework, org.apache.commons.collections, org.apache.commons.collections.buffer</Import-Package>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Activator>${pom.groupId}.impl.NetworkBridgeApp</Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <groupId>org.DX_57.osgi.NB_27</groupId>
</project>
```

When I replace maven-bundle-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin with maven-assembly-plugin the native library is included into the bundle. How I can create OSGI bundle and include native library during build time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the Maven Bundle Plugin has specific provisions for native code, and I don't think you need them: all the support you need is already there. You will need

- to include the native libraries using the `<Include-Resource>` instruction, and
- include the `Bundle-NativeCode` header in the instructions, just as you would when building the manifest by hand.